# Translation of "she conquered her demons and wore her scars like wings"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Latin has always been so intriguing to me. I want to get a tattoo with the quote "she conquered her demons and wore her scars like wings," in Latin. I am aware of how unreliable software translators can be and have tried a range of sources but always receive a varied or completely different result. I was hoping one of you would be able to tell me the correct way of phrasing this quote in Latin or tell me where I could find this information?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest:

> Daemonibus suis victis cicatrices pro alis gessit.

⋯ or if you prefer (being somewhat more literal and explicit about who conquered the demons, plus flexing your knowledge of Greek declension):

> Daemonas suos vicit et cicatrices pro alis gessit.

It is just in the nature of Latin that none of these sentences let on what gender the subject is. (It really depends on the verb, “she avenged” would be *ulta est*, in that case it's clearly a girl/woman.) You could make that explicit (*⋯ victis **ea** cicatrices ⋯*, for example), but it sounds contrived.

Comment: Maybe *illa*, like in *ille mi par*, or *haec*?